# Interrupts in MSP430F in C

Tags: c, msp430

I'm trying develop a program for the micro MSP430F1X, I'm want to simulate widescreen wipe so the idea is having 2 pin P1.0 and P1.1 as input to increase or decrease the state (been 0=stop, 1=PWM 50%, 2=PWM 75%, 3=1sec ON / 2sec OFF and repeat). At the moment I've been able to generate PWM=50%, but when I try to make a loop with a switch case routine inside the WDT interrupt it seems that it does not go into the switch I don't know why, can somebody help me please,(I'm not sure if the switch case should be implemented in the WDT interrupt or in the main function, here is my code:

```
#define STATE_IDLE 0
#define STATE_INTER 3
#define STATE_LOW 1
#define STATE_HIGH 2
#define WDT_MDLY_0_5 (WDTPW+WDTTMSEL+WDTCNTCL+WDTIS1)
int cnt=0;         // global variable to count timer ticks
static int speed=0;

void main(void) {
   // WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; //stop watchdog timer
   WDTCTL = WDT_MDLY_0_5; 
  IE1 |= WDTIE; 
   _EINT(); 
   P1DIR &= ~(BIT0+BIT1); 
    P1IES &= ~BIT0; 
    P1IES &= ~BIT1; 

    P1IE |= BIT0; 
    P1IE |= BIT1; 

    P1DIR |= BIT4; 
    for (;;) {
     }
  }



   void interrupt [WDT_VECTOR] tick(void) {
     while(1){
          if (speed==1){
           P1IFG &= ~BIT4; 
           if (++cnt == 200) { 
                      cnt = 0;
                      P1OUT^=BIT4;
                      }
             }
         }
  }

void interrupt [PORT1_VECTOR] p1Edge(void) { 

          if (P1IN & BIT0) {
                       speed=1;
                       P1IES &= ~BIT0; 
                       P1IE |= BIT4; // enable P1.4 interrupts

                    if (speed==1){
                        speed=2;
                        P1IE |= BIT4; // enable P1.4 interrupts
                        }
                    else if(speed==2){
                         speed=3;
                         P1IE |= BIT4; // enable P1.4 interrupts
                         }

                  }

      if (P1IN & BIT1) {

                            // P1.1 is now high -
                    P1IES &= ~BIT1; 

                    if (speed==3){
                        speed=2;
                        P1IE |= BIT4; // enable P1.4 interrupts
                        }
                    else if(speed==2){
                         speed=1;
                         P1IE |= BIT4; // enable P1.4 interrupts
                         }
                    else if(speed==1)
                         speed=0;
                    P1IE |= BIT4; // enable P1.4 interrupts

                  }
     }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do, but the infinite loop (`while(1)`) in the interrupt handler is certainly wrong.

Comment: Isn't the WDT for the watchdog interrupt?  Doesn't the watchdog interrupt result in a hardware reset event?  Why use the watchdog interrupt, which has unwanted side effects when there are timer peripherals with timer interrupts available?